# Service and AlarmManager

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

here is what am trying to accomplish and badly failing at it.

I need to:

-start a service

-do some tasks

-set AlarmManager to start the service again after a set period of time

-stop the service

the problem I'm having is that the service is being re-started almost immediately it is being stopped. All I want is that the service should start after the alarm goes off..

Here is the code:-

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(ThisService.this,
                            ThisService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ThisService.this, 0,
                                    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                            getUpdateTime(), getUpdateTime(), pendingIntent);
     stopSelf();
```

Comment: Where is the code? Add here

Comment: after you do some task for 1st service use **stopService()** pass an intent to your service class, then after the service is stopped you can create an instance of alarmmanager and start service again after some time 

check this too http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent)

Comment: I just want to stop the current service and have the AlarmManager create the same service again after some time

Comment: ^this is how i stopped my service then again created an instance of alarm manager class to set alarm with interval 15minutes and again started service

Comment: use IntentService as it will stop when task is complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are missing is the broadcast reciever

The flow should be

1. Start Service.
2. Create a BroadCast Reciever
3. Perform Task in service
4. Set Alarm to Trigger BroadCast Recievr( on Reception of bradcast reciever start Service again.)
5. Call StopSelf it will stop your service which can be restarted from broadcast recievr

please refer to http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

---

```
//-----Set the alarm to trigger the broadcast reciver-----------------------------
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
      alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
        + (i * 1000), pendingIntent);
      Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in " + i + " seconds",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//---------------Call StopSelf here--------------------

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------




public class MyBroadcastReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

//-----------write code to start the service--------------------------
     }

    }
```

Comment: tried it.. still no success.. it is still not getting delayed.. the service is being called back immediately. Am guessing the parameters for the `setRepeating()` method maybe incorrect...

Comment: if you are setting alarm just once use set instead not set repeating

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(ThisService.this,ThisService.class); what is this ? you are trying to call a service by itself thats poor stuff.wait I am updating my answer to include some code

Comment: I tried with the `set()` method earlier... what i was doing was:- `alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (i * 1000), pendingIntent);`

Thanx man!!!